# I need a straight forward simple how to for nautilus clutter

Tags: gnome, nautilus-elementary, clutter

I have followed many how-to videos, but those just wont work. Could someone tell me or link me to a straightforward working video? I currently do not have nautilus-elementary installed, in the past I've installed it but the function still didn't work.

Comment: Are you referring to the "Cover Flow" effect, as seen in the following picture? http://lh3.ggpht.com/_hQHFmaMqmyg/S32PF9b-h6I/AAAAAAAAARM/0KnN2Ch4K9s/s720/clutter.png

Comment: PLease be more specific
Do you want to know how to install nautilus elementary ? or Do you have any problems with your nautilus elementary installed

Answer (score 2):

Install Nautilus elementary with clutter view from ppa using the link below

[How to install nautilus elementary on ubuntu 10.10 with clutter view from ppa](http://open-help.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-install-nautilus-elementary-on.html)

and if you see only a blank screen when you try to enable clutter view it's a bug try this link for a work around.

[How to fix the blank screen on clutterview problem on ubuntu 10.10 maverick meerkat](http://open-help.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-fix-blank-screen-on-clutterview.html)

Hope this answers all your queries

Comment: If you paste the solution here, it would be more helpful. Links may go down in the future.